# Get items in multidimensional array separately

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array ($myArray) like this:

```
print_r(array_values ($myArray));

result: Array ( 
    [0] => 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1 
        [name] => ABC 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [id] => 2 
        [name] => DEF 
    ) 
)
```

I'm trying to get each ID and NAME.. So Im trying this:

```
foreach ($myArray as $value) {
    foreach($value as $result) {
        echo $result;
    }
}
```

I'm facing two problems:

1. I get a PHP WARNING that says: " Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 29

`This line is: foreach($value as $result) {`

2. I would like to get keys to ID and NAME to place them in correct places. This ways echo "1ABC" and "2DEF"

Any idea? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, the error triggered, since the array in your example (index zero in particular) is not an array (most likely an empty string/null ) which is being used inside foreach.

Since one of the elements is not an array, you could just check that if its an array or not using `is_array()`:

```
foreach($myArray as $values) {
    if(is_array($values)) {
        echo $values['id'] . ' ' . $values['name'] . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use `array_filter()` in this case which in turn removes that empty index zero, so that you could just use that loop that you have. You wouldn't have to check for that empty element.

```
$myArray = array_filter($myArray);
foreach ($myArray as $value) {
    foreach($value as $result) {
        echo $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Simple and I just couldnt see it! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
foreach (array_slice($myArray ,1) as $value) {
  foreach($value as $result) {
    echo $result;
  }
}
```

the 1st position is empty so omit first position